# Update multiple semantic ui react dropdown keys to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using  [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-item-content) to render some selection options in a dropdown .

I have a child component that is mapping over an array of object and returning some keys. So I supplied the following to the `options` prop for the semantic ui dropdown

```
      <Dropdown
        id="slotId"
        value={slotId}
        initialized={initialized}
        onChange={onSlotIdChange}
        selection
        fluid
        placeholder="Please select a slot id"
        clearable
        options={slots.map(slotId => {
          return {
            text: slotId.slotId,
            value: slotId.slotId,
            key: slotId.slotId,
            description: `Initialized: ${slotId.initialized}`,
            initialized: slotId.initialized
          };
        })}
      />
```

I'm lifting up state to the parent where I have the `changeHandler` defined

```
onSlotIdChange = async (e, { value, initialized }) => {
this.setState(
  { slotId: value, initialized: initialized, isLoading: false },
  () => {
    console.log(
      "chosen slotId updated to state, callback -->",
      this.state.slotId
    );
    console.log("initialized", this.state.initialized);
  }
);

if (!value) {
  this.handleClear();
  return;
}
};
```

I have a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/initialize-slot-6izhq) here with the issue.

Basically when I make the selection of the `slotId` it updates the `slotId` value to state, but I also want to update the `initialized` value to state as well. So For example, in the codesanbox, If you choose `slotId: 1` from the dropdown I also want a state variable `initialized` to update with the value of `Y`.

I'm struggling with getting the `initialized` key from the child to update with the selected Id in the parent. It's only being set to an empty `""` instead of the initialized value of Y or N.

I think the way semantic handles event changes only the `value` key is recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was because on your `Dropdown` component's options, you value only includes the `slotId`:

```
          options={slots.map(slot => {
              return {
                key: slot.slotId,
                text: slot.slotId,
                value: slot.slotId, // <--- this value here
                description: `Initialized: ${slot.initialized}`,
                initialized: slot.initialized
              };
            })}
```

To receive more information, you can either update the `value` returned:

```
         <Dropdown
            id="slotId"
            value={slotId}
            initialized={initialized}
            onChange={onSlotIdChange}
            selection
            fluid
            placeholder="Please select a slot id"
            clearable
            options={slots.map(slot => {
              return {
                key: slot.slotId,
                text: slot.slotId,
                value: { slotId: slot.slotId, initialized: slot.initialized },
                description: `Initialized: ${slot.initialized}`,
                initialized: slot.initialized
              };
            })}
          />
```

or pass in the third argument on `onChange` callback:

```
          <Dropdown
            id="slotId"
            value={slotId}
            initialized={initialized}
            onChange={(e, d) => onSlotIdChange(e, d, slots.find(s => s.slotId === d.value).initialized)}
            selection
            fluid
            placeholder="Please select a slot id"
            clearable
            options={slots.map(slot => {
              return {
                key: slot.slotId,
                text: slot.slotId,
                value: slot.slotId,
                description: `Initialized: ${slot.initialized}`,
                initialized: slot.initialized
              };
            })}
          />
```

or update the `data` returned to include with the found `initialized` value similar to the second approach above. Whichever that suits you best!